# Saving a screen's state, then navigating back to that screen later and resuming state

Tags: flutter

What I want to do is when I navigate to a certain screen, I want to save that screen somehow almost like a session, that I can later go back to and resume where it was left off.

The issue is I am using a custom bottomSheet on my Scaffold, this is for my bottom navigation. I know some bottom nav plugins use Tabs, but I am not doing it that way. So basically the "main" screen of the app, I need to save its state, so that whenever the "main" screen's button is clicked in the bottomSheet (navigation bar) it just goes back to where it was previously, instead of loading a brand new screen.

I briefly read the flutter docs on navigation and routing, I did not see anything specifically stating how to do this. I am thinking some way to name the pages in the stack, then later return to a specific page in the stack.

Comment: I think you could add toJson method to your State object, and then return all your State variables in Json format. Next - save the Json somewhere - maybe use sharedPreferences. Finally, in your initState - you would read the state from SharedPreferences and update your variables.